# How to publish PMD / Checkstyle / FindBugs / jUnit results before Jenkins pipeline will finish

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

PMD, Checkstyle, FindBugs publish results after pipeline finished, but if one of pipeline's stage has an **input** , and the **input** is waiting for an action then PMD/Checkstyle/FindBugs will never publish.
How to publish results before Jenkins pipeline will finish ?

**Pipeline example**:

```
node {

   stage('Preparation') {
   echo "Preparation"
   }

   stage('Build') {
     echo "build"

     sh "echo '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <checkstyle version=\"7.6.1\"><file name=\"Test.java\"><error line=\"5\" severity=\"warning\" message=\"Using the **** form of import should be avoided - java.util.*.\" source=\"com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.imports.AvoidStarImportCheck\"/></file></checkstyle>' >  checkstyle-result.xml"
     step([$class: 'hudson.plugins.checkstyle.CheckStylePublisher', pattern: '**/checkstyle-result.xml', unstableTotalAll:'0'])

     sh "echo '<testsuite tests=\"3\"><testcase classname=\"foo1\" name=\"ASuccessfulTest\"/><testcase classname=\"foo2\" name=\"AnotherSuccessfulTest\"/><testcase classname=\"foo3\" name=\"AFailingTest\"><failure type=\"NotEnoughFoo\"> details about failure </failure></testcase></testsuite>' >  junit-result.xml"
     junit 'junit-result.xml'

   }

    stage('Deploy') {
    echo "deploy"
    input "Deploy ?"
   }
}
```

After *Preparation* and *Build* stages I can see:

- current build status (unstable, yellow color)
- [checkstyle and jUnit status results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn4Vt.png) (if I go deeper to current build number)

> I don't see any changes on the ["main" job page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5muUQ.png) until press **Deploy**

Comment: Have you tried putting the `junit` step (or whatever you have there at the end) right before the `input`? Please paste your code here.

Comment: done, edited my question, checked jUnit - result is the same